# Could "correctly synchronized" be applied to a class instead of the whole program?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model, jls

There is a term *correctly synchronized* [in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races.
>
> If a program is correctly synchronized, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent (§17.4.3).

Can this *correctly synchronized* be applied to something smaller than the whole program, like some collection class?

In other words, imagine that I want to create my custom concurrent collection class.
I want the code of my collection to never produce data races in any program which uses my collection.
Would it be enough to only check that every possible sequential execution has no data races in order to guarantee that non-sequential executions also cannot produce data races?

Comment: It's customary to refer to some classes as "thread safe" if all methods use the keyword `synchronized` for example, or if the class is immutable.  There can be some debate over exactly what that means and how it should be implemented, so I think it's best to add an implementation note what is going on.  To summarize: I think you can say that a class is "correctly synchronized," but be aware that some folks might debate you.

Comment: I use the term _correctly synchronized_ as it's defined in the JLS (the quote is given in the question).

Comment: @markspace regarding the term "thread safe" I prefer the definition from Java Concurrency in Practice:
_"A class is thread-safe if it behaves correctly when accessed from multiple threads, regardless of the scheduling or interleaving of the execution of those threads by the runtime environment, and with no additional synchronization or other coordination on the part of the calling code."_

Comment: @JJJ, Re, "correctly synchronized," I _mostly_ agree with the Brian Goetz definition, but it only works if everybody agrees on what "behaves correctly" means. Sometimes, what is "correct" for a class that can be used in a multi-threaded environment is not always obvious. Sometimes, I like to say that a class is "thread safe" if it doesn't do anything in a multi-threaded program that would surprise a competent developer _who has read the documentation._

Comment: @markspace I suppose I can rephrase the question this way: imagine that I want to create a thread-safe collection. In order to guarantee thread-safety of my collection I can use happens-before, but then I would have to check all possible executions. The JLS provides a way to reduce the number of executions to check for the whole program  - it's called "correctly synchronized" and it requires checking of only sequential executions. I'm asking if this method can be used on just my collection class, not only on the whole program.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't use "correctly synchronized" as a synonym for "thread safe". I use "correctly synchronized" as it's defined in the JLS: the quote with the definition is given in the question. In short "correctly synchronized" == "you only need to check that sequential executions have no data races, and then you are automatically guaranteed that every execution will have no data races, and that every execution will be sequentially consistent".

Comment: D'Oh!. I did not mean to say "correctly synchronized." I meant to say "thread-safe." At the same time as I was typing that comment, I also was pondering a possible answer\* to your question, and I guess I mixed them up. Sorry. [\* I decided against actually answering though.]

Comment: @JJJ the quoted text says “*sequentially consistent*” which does *not* mean “sequential executions”. Any non-trivial program still has a practically infinite number of “possible executions”, even when correctly synchronized, so this formal definition was never meant as a “check them all” tool. Besides that, §17.4.3. says “*If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.*” so you would have to assume that there are no data races before you can rely on the sequential consistency to “prove” the correctness with circular reasoning…

Comment: @Holger I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I could replace "sequential execution" with "sequentially consistent execution" in the question, but IMO the meaning would stay the same: we only need to check that sequential (or SC) executions has no data races in order to guarantee that every possible execution has no data races + in this case every possible execution will appear to be sequential (or SC). (this is what the quote in the question says)

Comment: @Holger _Any non-trivial program still has a practically infinite number of “possible executions”, even when correctly synchronized, so this formal definition was never meant as a “check them all” tool_ How do you know what the authors of the JMM meant? IMO since only SC executions need to be checked for the absence of data races, then it's possible to create a tool that does it automatically.

Comment: @Holger _so you would have to assume that there are no data races before you can rely on the sequential consistency_ No. You can rely on SC after you check that there are no data races in SC executions of your program. The quote I gave in the question (from [§17.4.5 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)) says literally that.

Comment: Do you know about the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)? It implies that you can not even prove whether the number of possible executions is finite or infinite, not to speak of the idea to check them all for the presence of data races. But anyway, there’s a much simpler practical consideration: if it was possible to write such a checking tool, what do you think is the reason that no such tool exist?

Comment: @Holger the halting problem means that there could be no algorithm that can efficiently determine if a program halts for EVERY POSSIBLE program, but an effective algorithm for some specific subset of programs is possible. In other words, there can be no tool that can effectively check for data races EVERY POSSIBLE java program, but a tool that works for some subset of java programs is possible. [Java Pathfinder](https://github.com/javapathfinder/jpf-core/wiki/Testing-vs.-Model-Checking) is one example of such tools.

Comment: @Holger Of course, as the program gets bigger the number of possible executions to check grows exponentially, but fortunately there are some tricks to deal with that. For example Lincheck (another similar tool which for some unknown reason doesn't have data race detection yet) allows modularity: if an object (no matter how complex it's inside) is linearizable, then we can consider all its methods atomic and ignore possible interleavings inside them - this drastically reduces the number of interleavings to check and allows us to create and check for data races very large programs.

Comment: @Holger [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-lincheck#modular-testing) the modularity in Lincheck is explained.

Comment: @Holger I hope that my original question is more clear to you now. The original question is also (kind of) about modularity: I ask if we can use "correctly synchronized" (as defined in the JLS) with a single class instead of the whole program.

Comment: correction: the number of possible SC executions grows not exponentially but [as _O(n!)_](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's possible.

If the internal state of the collection is not accessible from the outside, then we can consider the corresponding to the state [shared variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1) (that is what the JLS operates with) in isolation from the shared variables in the rest of the program.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421466) cites the proof for the whole program. But as I understand, the proofs for both Lemma 2 and Theorem 3 holds even if we add additional restriction that we only consider some shared variables.
Don't take my word for it and check [the proofs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421466) yourself, but to me it seems like it works.
This holds as long as all the actions (reads and writes) on the selected shared variables are taken into consideration.

P.S. it's totally possible when simultaneously:

- actions on the selected shared variables (the ones which constitute the internal state of our collection) are sequentially consistent
- actions on the ignored shared variables contain data races

because:

1. it's always possible to find a total order of all actions in an execution, consistent with program order and synchronization order. From [the citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421466):

   > A topological sort on the happens-before edges of the actions in an execution gives a total order consistent with program order and synchronization order.
2. actions on a shared variable are sequentially consistent if every read of the variable returns the latest (in this total order) write to the variable.
3. actions on a shared variable are non-sequentially-consistent if there is a read of the variable which returns a write to the variable that is not the latest (in this total order).
4. it's possible when both (2) and (3) are present in the execution

Comment: thank you, I think you are right: the proofs remain valid when only some shared variables are considered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that there would be no *race conditions* is your concurrent custom collection.

I.e. multiple threads can access the same element simultaneously only if they are trying to read its value, that's fine. But if it's possible if one thread is trying to update the element while another is trying to retrieve its value, or multiple threads a trying to change the same element at the same time (overriding results produced by one-another), that's a problem. And it can be avoided by synchronizing the mutating code.

[§17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> When a program contains two **conflicting accesses** (§17.4.1) that are not ordered by a happens-before relationship, it is said to contain a **data race**.

[§17.4.1. Shared Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1)

> Two accesses to (reads of or writes to) the same variable are said to be **conflicting** if at least **one of the accesses is a write**.

Here's a dummy example of the concurrent list which allows reading its value from multiple threads simultaneously, but if one of the threads is writing a value, all others would be blocked.

This can be achieved by using [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

```
public class MyConcurrentArrayList<T> {
    private Object[] array;
    private int size;
    
    private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock read = lock.readLock();
    private final Lock write = lock.readLock();
    
    // non-mutating operation
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T get(int i) {
        T result;
        
        read.lock(); // lock the read-lock, from that moment only non-mutating operations (guarded by the readLock) are allowed
        // access the element under the given index
        try {
            result = (T) array[i];
        } finally {
            read.unlock(); // release the read-lock
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    // mutating operation
    public void add(T item) {
        write.lock(); // lock the write-lock, none of the threads would be able to read or update the list until this lock is not released
        
        try {
            // check if the list needs to grow (omitted)

            array[size++] = item; // add a new element
        } finally {
            write.unlock(); // release the write-lock
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that I _"need to ensure that there would be no race conditions is your concurrent custom collection"_. My question is about one of the potential ways of achieving that. My first step is to make sure there are no data races. The (mentioned by you) happens-before requires checking of ALL POSSIBLE executions for that. My question is whether I can use _"correctly synchronized"_ technique, which is also described in the JLS and which only require checking of SEQUENTIAL executions (there are much fewer of them).

Comment: @JJJ There many ways to synchronize the code. You can use [`Lock`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html), or [`synchronized` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) to guard the critical sections of the code.

Comment: @JJJ I've provided a dummy example of how to synchronize an `ArrayList` using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the different ways to synchronize code in java. I'm asking about one specific method that the JLS provides us to validate that programs have no data races. The method is described in the JLS as "correctly synchronized programs". The method is pretty cheap and guarantees that the program always executes as-if-serial.

Comment: @JJJ You said that you understand that you understand what **data race** is. When your concurrent implementation is free from *data race* it considered to be correctly synchronized. Makes sense? How to validate - **inspect the data flow**. Java Language Specification is not a testing tutorial (I don't understand what else you want find in JLS). You need to apply the means of synchronization in a way that prevent *data race*, i.e. - find the critical sections of the code and determine how they need to locked. And there's no one single correct way to apply synchronization.

Comment: _"When your concurrent implementation is free from data race it considered to be correctly synchronized. Makes sense?"_ I took the term "correctly synchronized" from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html) - there it's different from "when your concurrent implementation is free from data race". The definition from the JLS is quoted at the start of my question. In addition to defining "correctly synchronized" the quote actually provides a cheap method of proving that a program has no data races (by only checking sequential executions).

Comment: @JJJ *"by only checking sequential executions"* - sure, that's what I meant while saying that you need to inspect the data flow in the all the methods accessing the shared resource (i.e. methods that need to be synchronized). What else do you want to find in JLS?

Comment: I'm not sure if _"by only checking sequential executions"_ can be applied to my custom collection class only (this is what I'm asking about). In the JLS "correctly synchronized" is defined for the program as a whole. But I want my collection to be data-race-free even in programs with data races. (And BTW any real program has data races because `String.hashCode()` contains data race).

Comment: @JJJ Do you understand the term *shared resource* (see the link "shared variables" in the answer) ? In a nutshell, it's a subject of concurrent access (e.g. `array` in the sample code in the answer). For your collection to be *thread safe*, **all** the behavior that that requires interaction with *shared resources* should be synchronized.

Comment: @JJJ Regarding *"program as a whole"* - apply encapsulation properly, synchronization should be exercised on the level of separate Classes (which own *shared resources*, and methods dialing with resources should be encapsulated within the class, and resources shouldn't be exposed outside the class). It not clear how `String` is related to your custom collection, if you're having hard time with synchronizing `hashCode()` method you might introduce a separate question and explain the problem in details. A quick suggestion - have a look at the code of legacy collections: `Vector` and `Hashtable`.

Comment: I cannot "apply encapsulation properly" because the guarantees for "correctly synchronized" are given in the JLS explicitly for the whole program. [The proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421466/20616873) is also for the whole program. I need a proof that "applying encapsulation properly" preserves the guarantees

Comment: @JJJ If there's at least one method which provides a possibility for the data of a *shared resource* to be corrupted, it doesn't matter how many methods you've synchronized. Your task is to identify every shared resource in the application, find the methods that make use of these resources, and each and every method guard a critical code section.

Comment: @JJJ *"proof that "applying encapsulation properly"* - If behavior that dials with a particular resource is bound to a particular class, i.e. there are no methods that make use of this resource other than by the means of the behavior you've synchronized than happens-before relationship is guaranteed for resource. If you're designing a collection in your project, then its underlying array or nodes would be a *shared resource*. If you synchronized all the collection behavior - it's thread-safe.

Comment: We've deviated from the topic too much.
I'm only interested if "correctly synchronized" (as it's defined in the JLS) can be used with a single class instead of the whole program. Discussions about "shared resources", "encapsulation" and other common practices of synchronization are too vague and off-topic to be useful in answering the question.

Comment: @JJJ There's nothing vague. That's what I refer to as a [*shared resource*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1) from the perspective of JSL. In a nutshell, it's what you're protecting through synchronization. It's the **core** of the subject. When there's no shared sources, that can be mutated, there's nothing to synchronize to begin with. Is that clear?